# How can I speed up combat without seriously altering the rules?

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse

**What are some alternate (possibly widely accepted and used homebrew) rules that could help simplify and speed up combat in Werewolf: The Apocalypse, without disrupting the overall game balance?**

It's the 2nd edition of the game that I'd like to hack, primarily, but answers regarding other editions may also help.

Comment: Playing werewolf (and many other WoD games) I never felt that combat took too long. Could you explain which part of combat is taking so much time? is it that the amount of dies thrown is too high, that characters sustain too much and a lot of hits must be dealt before someone is seriously injured? Please elaborate if you can and I'll try to answer.